# QGIS 2.18.x - GRASS 7.2.x installation in Linux deepin 15.4: which repository to use?

Tags: qgis

In the default linux deepin repository there is the QGIS LTS 2.14.x version. Which repository could I use (if possible) to install the stable version 2.18.x?

Comment: Since Deepin claims to be based on Debian unstable, I suggest `http://qgis.org/debian sid main`. I don't have it myself, so I can not test it.

Comment: Since QGIS 2.14 is running for you, try `apt-cache depends qgis` to get the dependencies of that, and compare it with http://qgis.org/debian/dists/sid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.